# How to configure RStudio to allow for WhiteSmith indentation?

Tags: r, rstudio, indentation

For details about this indentation pattern, please see: http://www.activeclickweb.com/whitesmiths/index.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style

Using R, here is an example basic function using this indentation style:

```
# this is "not" recursive at the moment ...
createDir = function (folder)
  {
  ifelse(!dir.exists(folder), dir.create(folder), "Folder exists already")
  }
```

Here is a switch statement inside a function using the same style:

```
buildX = function(n,method)
  {
  switch(method,
         "rnorm-0-1" = rnorm(n,0,1),
         "rgama-1-0.5" = rgamma(n,1,1/2),
         rnorm(n,0,1) # default case of switch
        );
  }
```

Here is another function, to conclude the examples:

```
buildY = function(resp, n, unif, myQ)
  {
  Y = numeric(n);
  for (i in 1:n)
    {
    Y[i] = mapY(i, unif, myQ, resp);
    }
  Y;
  }
```

How do I configure RStudio to use this indentation style?  Will it work when I copy an paste?

And bonus for an answer to the ability to highlight the two braces more readily, like Notepad++ does?  I can click on the right/left side of the open/close brace and it highlights, and even creates a vertical line connecting the braces ...

[image: brace highlighting]